# Find FIRST row that satisfies conditions using either Numpy array or Pandas dataframe. (possibly tricky)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I will ask the question in a library agnostic manner as one may be better than the other in this instance. Or maybe another magical library exists?

I have a DB table of about 10,000 records and I know how to create a numpy array or dataframe from it. The data is like so.

```
   ...
   20,25,1,5
   20,25,2,3
   20,25,4,21
   20,25,5,1
   20,25,9,19
   ...
   45,47,6,20
   45,47,10,2
   45,47,11,56
   45,47,21,41
   ...
```

In the example search criteria below I am after the value '20' in col4 of this row.

```
45,47,6,20
```

1. Notice the first 2 columns have the same values and define a group.
2. Col2 will always be >= to col1 in a row.
3. The values in col3 will always be in ascending sequence within a group and not necessarily contiguous.

I am after the value of the cell in col4 using the following search criteria.

I know how to use a mask in numpy to find all the rows whose values are eg 'col1 >= 45 AND col2 <= 47'.
I have a third search value of eg '8' that is to be used to search col3 within the above group (col1, col2, 45 -> 47)

**I need to find the FIRST row whose value in col3 <= 8.**

Therefore I need to search the rows that have 'col1 >= 45 AND col2 <= 47' in a col3 DESCENDING sequence until row '45,47,6,20' is found. I am after the value '20' in col4.

There will only ever be at most 1 row that will match. It is possible that no row will match the criteria (eg if col3 search value was '3').

I need to do 100s of 1000s of searches at a time so would prefer that no new arrays or dataframes be created unless that has a minimal impact on resources.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output. same way u posted ur original dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

1. filter the dataframe to only keep the lines matching the criteria
2. groupby on first 2 columns
3. apply `tail(1)` on each group to find the relevant line per group, if any

Code would be:

```
df[(df['col1']>=45)&(df['col2']<=47)&(df['col3']<=8)].groupby(['col1', 'col2']
                                                              ).tail(1)
```

With your sample, it gives as expected

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
5    45    47     6    20
```

The good news is that you can search multiple groups in one pass, and it still gives expected results if no rows match the criteria. Demo:

```
>>> df[(df['col1']>=20)&(df['col2']<=47)&(df['col3']<=8)].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).tail(1)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
3    20    25     5     1
5    45    47     6    20
>>> df[(df['col1']>=20)&(df['col2']<=47)&(df['col3']<=3)].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).tail(1)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1    20    25     2     3
>>> df[(df['col1']>=45)&(df['col2']<=47)&(df['col3']<=3)].groupby(['col1', 'col2']).tail(1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3, col4]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a multiindex for the three first columns and a mask on this multiindex as follows:

```
# I reproduce a similar dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
v1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
v2 = v1 + 2
v3 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
v4 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({"v1": v1,
                   "v2": v2,
                   "v3": v3,
                   "v4": v4})
# and sort it according to your comments
df = df.sort_values(by=["v1", "v2", "v3"])
df.head()
```

I get the following dataframe:

```
  v1  v2  v3  v4
8   0   2   4   0
7   1   3   0   8
9   1   3   1   7
3   1   3   9   4
1   2   4   0   3
```

```
# parameters for research
val1 = 1 # the equivalent of your 45
val2 = 3 # the equivalent of your 47
val3 = 2 # the equivalent of your 8

# Set the multiindex
hdf = df.set_index(["v1", "v2", "v3"]).sort_index(ascending=False)
hdf.tail()
```

Your dataframe now looks as follows:

```
          v4
v1 v2 v3    
2  4  0    3
1  3  9    4
      1    7
      0    8
0  2  4    0
```

```
# Define the mask
mask = (hdf.index.get_level_values("v1") >= val1) & \
        (hdf.index.get_level_values("v2") <= val2) &\
        (hdf.index.get_level_values("v3") <= val3)

# Select only the first row returned by the selection using cumsum on mask
print(hdf.loc[mask & (mask.cumsum() == 1), ["v4"]])
```

And you get:

```
          v4
v1 v2 v3    
1  3  1    7
```

Comment: Sorry but I need the row 1,3,1,7 using your data and search criteria of 1,3,2 because searching the 1,3 group in descending sequence would result in the v3=1 cell as the FIRST value that is <= to 2. NOTE I said 'I need to find the FIRST row whose value in col3 <= 8.' (I had @Raphaele Adjerad at the start of my comment but it disappeared.)

Comment: @notIntoXS I modifed the answer to sort the index in descending order. Therefore you search the multiindex in the order you wanted here

Comment: OK thank you very much @Raphaele Adjerad. I will digest your code and see how I go. But first I have to do some other coding unfortunately. Will try within 24 hours.